# xsl transform remove double tags

Tags: xslt

I have som XML I need to transform to remove double tags.

Originally I used:

```
<xsl:template match="*[name()=name(../..)]"></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[name()=name(../../..)]"></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[name()=name(..)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Which together removed the inner of two tags with the same name. But that only works well if there is only one inner tag.

I have:

```
<a>
 <a>
    <b>xxxx</b>
    <c>xxxx</c>
 </a>
 <a>
    <b>yyyy</b>
    <c>yyyy</c>
 </a>
</a>
```

I want to end up with:

```
 <a>
    <b>xxxx</b>
    <c>xxxx</c>
 </a>
 <a>
    <b>yyyy</b>
    <c>yyyy</c>
 </a>
```

Rather than:

```
 <a>
    <b>xxxx</b>
    <c>xxxx</c>
    <b>yyyy</b>
    <c>yyyy</c>
 </a>
```

I know very little about XSL transform and the search syntax, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The output you are asking for is not well-formed XML (lacks a root element). Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes. The above is a snippet. <a> is not the root element. Thanks for pointing that out. <a> is about three or four levels deep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet will remove the **outer** (parent) elements whose children all have the same name:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- exception for parent whose children have all the same name -->
<xsl:template match="*[*][not(*[name()!=name(..)])]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to the following test input:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <a>
            <b>bbb</b>
            <c>ccc</c>
        </a>
        <a>
            <d>
                <d>ddd</d>      
            </d>
            <e>eee</e>
            <f>
                <f>fff</f>  
                <g>ggg</g>  
            </f>
        </a>
    </a>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a>
      <b>bbb</b>
      <c>ccc</c>
   </a>
   <a>
      <d>ddd</d>
      <e>eee</e>
      <f>
         <f>fff</f>
         <g>ggg</g>
      </f>
   </a>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing the child when its name matches the parent it sounds like you really want to remove the *parent* when its name is the same as all its children:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*][not(*[name() != name(..)])]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

You can read the second match expression as "any element X that has at least one child element and also does not have any child element with a name that is different from X".

Comment: You are eliminating leaf elements as well.

Comment: Looks like some of the right stuff. For some reason, all but the first of the innermost tags containing data gets removed (except for their data, which is now one long string inside the inner <a> tag.
I'm also doing some other transformations, so there might be something from there...

Comment: @michael.hor257k true, I've edited now to restrict that template to non-leaf elements only.

Comment: @michael.hor257k ... which I now see is the same as your answer - I didn't see that til after my edit as the link brought me straight to your comment

Comment: Yes, it's the same. I'll take that as a compliment. :-)